# running bash script with node, containing functions in script

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, package.json

Hi I am trying to run a bash script from the package.json in node.

(I know I could just use node instead of bash, but I already have written a bunch of code in bash and don't want to migrate immediately.) (Note I am on MacOS).

Inside the script I have various bash functions.

I have tried loading with various commands (code snippet of package.json):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "sh ./loadScripts.sh",
    "serve": "bash ./loadScripts.sh",
    "serve2": "source ./loadScripts.sh",
    "serve3": "./loadScripts.sh",
  },
}
```

However even though all of these load the script, when I try to use a function inside the script, say I try to run myFunction in the terminal after, then it says command not found.

However if I load the script directly in the terminal by typing
`source ./loadScripts.sh` it seems to work fine and I can use the functions I have defined in the script.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: A `source ....` affects the shell it runs in (and, with respect to environment variables, also its child processes). A `source ....` in a shell inside some node.js process affects therefore exactly that shell, but not magically the one you are in.